# How to set up python3 REPL in Sublime Text3

Tags: windows-10, sublimetext3, python-3.6

So I tried in a new created file:
python3.sublime-build with the following code

```
{
  "cmd": ["C:\Users\AA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe", "$file"], 
  "selector": "source.python", 
  "file_regex": "file \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]+)"
}
```

And modified the Main.sublime-menu with:

```
{"command": "repl_open",
                    "caption": "Python3 - RUN current file",
                    "id": "repl_python_run",
                    "mnemonic": "p",
                    "args": {
                        "type": "subprocess",
                        "encoding": "utf8",
                        "cmd": ["python3", "-u", "$file_basename"],
                        "cwd": "$file_path",
                        "syntax": "Packages/Python/Python.tmLanguage",
                        "external_id": "python",
                        "extend_env": {"PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8"}
                            }
                    },
```

However, when i run the

> tools>SubimeREPL>Python>Python3 - RUN current file

from the Sublime Text3 menu bar, i receive a:

> "FileNotFoundError(2, 'The system cannot find the file
>   specified.'None'2)"

Which i have no idea what i am missing.

Comment: One issue that you have is that `sublime-build` files are JSON files, and in JSON the `\` character is an escape character, so you need to either double them up in your path (`c:\\users\\aa`) or use forward slashes instead, which windows should be fine with IIRC (`c:/users/aa`). This may be the reason it can't find your python interpreter.

Comment: If the REPL is using the command as referenced from the main menu (I assume so but I don't use that package), it's not connecting with the build system you defined, it's specifically just trying to run `python3`, in which case you should make sure that the command is in your system PATH.

Comment: Worked.  Thanks very much indeed.  
- I had to double the  \\ in the sublime build 
and 
- change in the Main.sublime-menu:  the actual full path to the python 3.

Would love to upvote, but i dont see this option. However, thanks for the help!